# How to sequence correctly with factory_girl in rails development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I want to integrate factory_girl in rails development environment for quickly creating records. However, every time I open rails console and do some actions, the sequence state always begins from zero, which leading to error of violating uniqueness. Such as:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Jim'
    email
  end

  sequence :email do |n| # every time n begins at 0
    "#{n}@exmaple.com"
  end
end
```

Do you have some simple solutions to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: Avoiding duplication errors in Factory Girl...am I doing it wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072199/rails-avoiding-duplication-errors-in-factory-girl-am-i-doing-it-wrong)

Comment: That is what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can set the initial value of `n` if you wish. you can achieve this by:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Jim'
    sequence :email, 100 do |n|
      "#{n}@exmaple.com"
    end
  end
end
```

**or**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :user do
        name 'Jim'
        sequence(:email, 100) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
      end
end
```

**note:** `n = 100 in this case` for more info check out the documentation [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences)

Comment: This will still be violating the uniqueness constraint. Each time I am opening a rails console or running a new test, it will start from 100. There will be flaky tests because of validation errors in the test suite.

Answer (score 3):

I think the original question was how to deal with the fact that sequences reset each time rails is restarted, not how to use sequences.  The easiest thing I've done for strings that need to be unique is to append a timestamp to the end of the string.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Jim'
    email { "jim_#{Time.now.to_f}@example.com" }
  end
end
```

This can also be combined with Faker, since Faker's unique call can time out or run out of options:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  name { Faker::Name.name + " #{Time.now.to_f}" }
  email { "#{name}@example.com" }
end
```

It makes for ugly strings, but you can truncate the timestamp a bit if you like, and it just works. As long as your test objects don't need to look nice, you can just slap the timestamp on the string and get on with your day.

Comment: I would do `"#{name.parameterize}@example.com"` to prevent spacing and special characters issues

Comment: `Time.now.seconds_since_midnight` is a handy already slightly truncated version :)

Answer (score 1):

You need the sequence statement inside of the `:user` factory definition:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Jim'
    sequence :email do |n|
      "#{n}@exmaple.com"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the sequence with `FactoryBot.rewind_sequences`.

I have this in my spec helper:

```
config.append_after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
  FactoryBot.rewind_sequences
end
```